# Get MATLAB to convert a date string from Excel into the correct MATLAB serial number

Tags: excel, matlab, date

I have had a real headache with taking dates from Excel and putting them into MATLAB as a MATLAB serial number. They are given to me as a DateString (e.g. Date = {'20/09/2014','23/09/2014',...}). I have used the MATLAB advised `datenum` function with the following `dd/mm/yyyy` to try an direct it into that form. However, it continues to forces it into the rather unhelpful mm/dd/yyyy serial form.

My exact code is:

```
Date = {'01/02/2014';'01/03/2014';'01/04/2014';'01/05/2014';'01/06/2014'}
Date = datenum({'01/02/2014';'01/03/2014';'01/04/2014';'01/05/2014';'01/06/2014'},'dd/mm/yyyy');
```

The results it gives me is:

`Date = 735601
      735602
      735603
      735604
      735605`
i.e. they are one day apart not one month or 30-ish days.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure about that? Running your code and then writing ``Date'`` returns: ``735631      735659      735690      735720      735751`` for me. Also ``datestr(Date(1))`` returns ``01-Feb-2014`` and ``datestr(Date(2))`` returns ``01-Mar-2014``, which all seems correct to me. Maybe you used ``'mm/dd/yyyy'`` as format before.

Comment: Almost certain. It is within a GUI but I have had this problem before in a normal script. However, you have made me question myself. I shall check yet again though!

Comment: I have now found the cause of my problem. It seems that there was a previous Date in the GUI that for some reason over rode what I had in the callback I was working in. So when I was changing the callback section it did nothing to change the datenum formate. Thank you for checking this though. I was going slightly mad. Do you think it is worth deleting the question now?

Comment: Now that you exactly know the problem, as well as the solution, I'd suggest to update the question and its title and tags accordingly (add GUI) and post your solution as an answer to this specific question.